# Report Error. Deserialization failed: The element 'TableCells' in namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I'm trying to create a new report in my asp.net application.  I'm using the report wizard to try to create my .rdlc file.  I am using a stored procedure defined in my linq to sql class.  After I complete the wizard steps I get the following error.  I can't seem to find much to trouble shoot this error.

> Deserialization failed: The element 'TableCells' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition:TableCell'. Line 125, position 32.

Answer (score 0):

Have you developed your report against a different version of sql to that which you're deploying it? E.g. have you developed it against SQL2008 and you're trying to deploy it against SQL2005?

Comment: Well I develop in 2008, but my SQl Server is 2005